# Pivot a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pivot

So i have a data frame

```
data = {
    'Type': ['Z', 'x', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'B','Z', 'x', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'B'],
    'Val': ['012', '11', '123', '567', '101', '22', 'T54', '111','012', '11', '123', '500', '101', '22', 'T54', '111']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: original data frame (df)]

I simply want to pivot this data frame maintaining the original order of the columns

so output will look like this

| Z | x | A | D | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | 11 | 123 | 22 | T54 |
| nan | nan | 567 | nan | 111 |
| nan | nan | 101 | nan | nan |
| 012 | 11 | 123 | 22 | T54 |
| nan | nan | 500 | nan | 111 |
| nan | nan | 101 | nan | nan |

note that the order of the columns should be maintained and whichever columns are repeating its value will keep getting added to new rows.

I have tried this code but unfortunately not getting the desired output

```
df['Type'] = pd.Categorical(df['Type'], categories=df['Type'].unique(), ordered=True)
df['Row'] = df.groupby('Type').cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='Row', columns='Type', values='Val')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None
```

[image: my output]

Comment: What should be the output if you replace the `Z` in row `8` by `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a double index, once to determine when the values restart to the beginning (taking advantage of your Categorical and of [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)+[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)), and once with the [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['Type'] = pd.Categorical(df['Type'], categories=df['Type'].unique(),
                            ordered=True)

out = (df
   .assign(idx=lambda d: d['Type'].lt(d['Type'].shift()).cumsum(),
           idx2=lambda d: d.groupby(['idx', 'Type']).cumcount(),
          )
   .pivot(index=['idx', 'idx2'], columns='Type', values='Val')
)
```

Output:

```
Type        Z    x    A    D    B
idx idx2                         
0   0     012   11  123   22  T54
    1     NaN  NaN  567  NaN  111
    2     NaN  NaN  101  NaN  NaN
1   0     012   11  123   22  T54
    1     NaN  NaN  500  NaN  111
    2     NaN  NaN  101  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It would be nice of you to clarify the logic as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76739610/edit) to the question (and eventually explain your chose of accepted answer). It's currently still unclear what is the exact expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `.groupby` + `.pivot_table`:

```py
def fn(x):
    x['idx'] = x.groupby('Type').cumcount()
    x = x.pivot_table(index='idx', columns='Type', values='Val', sort=False, aggfunc='first')
    return x

out = df.groupby((df['Type'] == df['Type'].unique()[0]).cumsum()).apply(fn).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Type    Z    x    A    D    B
0     012   11  123   22  T54
1     NaN  NaN  567  NaN  111
2     NaN  NaN  101  NaN  NaN
3     012   11  123   22  T54
4     NaN  NaN  500  NaN  111
5     NaN  NaN  101  NaN  NaN
```

---

To remove index/column names you can do then

```py
out.index.name, out.columns.name = None, None
```

Comment: I suspect this would fail if you replace the second `Z` by `x` (although OP should clarify the behaviour)

Comment: @mozway Yes, but what should one do in this case? Perhaps there's always `Z` present.

Comment: Yes that's a good question, I asked OP

Comment: no don't worry the 2nd Z would never be replaced with any other value thanks it worked.

Comment: ooops it seems that if Z occurs again it is not capturing

Comment: Why don't you explain the exact logic and constraints in the question? We **guessed** what we thought is the logic but we shouldn't have to ;)

Comment: ok so 2nd solution worked so Think of Z as some sort of qualifier Whenever Z occurs 1st from there till next until next Z occurs will be my one group. so Z can occur multiple times and whenever it occurs it follows the same structure after that i.e (Z,x,A,D,B). Also we have no control over the repetitions any column can repeat any number of times